# Is https with no encryption key secure?

Tags: php, encryption

Hy, I hired a web hosting service that offers https.
To browse my site, even when I only type the simple MyWebUrl.com the browser switches to https and shows the little lock on the URL line.

But my php pages are precisely the same I used before in my old host provider that did not offer https.

The question is: How secure is the connection and data flowing on it?
Is my data been encrypted?
Do I really have to go through the process of changing every single page in order to include some sort of encryption key to make it secure?

Thanks
Paulo.

Comment: The encryption occurs between the client and the server. It decrypts at the server and when your PHP gets it it is already decrypted. Same with the browser, browser decrypts and displays at it should be. Secures against man in the middle only. You still can be SQL injected, XSS, remote file, etc. still. Might be worth looking at https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/20803/how-does-ssl-tls-work

Comment: My main concern is in fact man in the middle, for SQL injections and other tricks I have other means that, for my purpose, I believe are enough.

Answer (score 3):

The setup of the Https connection is handled on the server serving and processing the php (apache2, nginx).

So **no** you should be able to enable this in for the entire application server, did the hosting provide you with a management interface (like directAdmin)?

Could it be that you redirect between pages using the whole URL (http://MyWebUrl.com/subdomainwewannegoto) and not the path?

Comment: Tom, thanks for the response. The hosting provider has an interface and I had to enable https manually for my domain. Even if I type http:// it will switch to https by itself and show the lock. I do not know what the server runs but I assume probably Apache. Should I consider my connection to the server secure and understand that a "middle man" somehow intercepting my web traffic will not be able to see clear text? Thanks

Comment: @paulo-borges in that case - yes, the traffic to your site is encrypted